# Understanding LIME output

Tags: python, output, lime

I try to understand this lime output

[image: exp.show_in_notebook() result]

the predicted value is the prediction made by the model we try to understand. But how are min and max calculated?
Another question: is RidgeRegressor the default explainable model used by the lime python package?